# Perturbation of an infinite-time horizon evolution system

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm dealing with an evolutionary problem described by the equation:
$$\dot y(t)=F(y(t)) +f(t), \quad y(0)=y_0$$
If I suppose that this equation has a solution in a variational sense over an infinite-time horizon, for a given initial data $y_0$ and $f$.

How to prove (if possible) that this solution depends continuously on data $f$ and $y_0$.

Comment: What is known about $F$?

Comment: In my situation. I have a regular domain $\Omega \subset R^n$ ,  $b \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and
$F(y)=\Delta y+b \nabla y$

Comment: It seems you are examining an inhomogeneous [convection-diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation). I would have thought there was lots of information out there on this very topic.

Comment: You're right, sir, a well-detailed article. However, I can't seem to find an answer to my question in there.